Keyboard dismisses after one letter typed
I have a ForEach loop of text fields that add the input into an array, the data is entered into the array correctly but the keyboard dismisses after each key press.
This is my code:
@State var acts: [String] = [""]
@State private var actcount = 1

var body: some View {
    ForEach($acts, id: \.self) { $act in
        HStack{
            TextField("", text: $act)
        }
        .padding(12)
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).foregroundStyle(.white))
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
    }

    if actcount != 10 {
        if actcount == 1 {
            Button{
                self.acts += [""]
                self.actcount += 1
            } label: {
                Text("Add Act")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .padding(6)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
            }
        } else {
            HStack{
                Button{
                    self.acts += [""]
                    actcount += 1
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Act")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(6)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
                }
                Button{
                    actcount -= 1
                    acts.removeLast()
                } label: {
                    Text("Remove Act")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(6)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I'm also geting the error:

-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID. inputModality = Keyboard, inputOperation = , customInfoType = UIEmojiSearchOperations


no its doing the same with that, i have to click on the field for each letter i type

Most likely this is due to $acts, id: \.self - you re using acts as ID. So when you change 1 character, the whole ForEach will rerender.
Instead at the minimum have acts as structure with ID separate from value, or isolate editing in other way (for example with the sub-component).

im quite new to swift, how would i have the id seperate from value

As @Timbre mentioned correctly in the comments, each item is identified as its content. So any change will cause the removal and rerender of a new one. To get around that, you can introduce a new identifier like the index of each Act:
ForEach(Array($acts.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { (index, $act) in 
{ ... }

Note that although this fixes the problem, it's not recommended, a better approach would be defining a separated entity like struct Act, making it identifiable, and handling the identification in a way that suits your needs:
struct Act: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID() //  Handle this in a proper way
    var text: String
}

@State var acts: [Act] = [Act(text: "")]

ForEach($acts) { $act in
   ...    
   TextField("", text: $act.text)
   ...


the struct act sorted that out but the function to upload the array of acts doesnt work anymore.                                     try await viewModel.uploadTicket(ticketname: ticketbio, bandnames: acts, bandcount: actcount, venue: venueName, date: startdate, price: ticketprice)

I don't know about the rest of your code my friend, that's a new question. For the minimal change, you can go with the first methods

As @Timbretimbre says in their comment, this is likely because you are using the string value as the ID in your ForEach.
Instead try this:
ForEach(Array(acts.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, act in

